# Workaround for the error while_loop() got an unexpected keyword argument 'maximum_iterations'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I got the following error when I tried to run the code :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, look_back)))
```

> TypeError: while_loop() got an unexpected keyword argument 'maximum_iterations'

I understood one of the solutions is to use another version of keras such as this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51573241/typeerror-while-loop-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-maximum-iterations). But I'm using my company's desktop and every uninstall and install have to go through my company's IT department. Is there another workaround that does not involve changing the version of keras?

My keras version is v2.2.4; tensoflow is v1.1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way, but it's not pretty. You could reach into TensorFlow internals and monkey-patch `while_loop` to ignore `maximum_iterations=`:

```
from tensorflow.python.ops import control_flow_ops

orig_while_loop = control_flow_ops.while_loop

def patched_while_loop(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs.pop("maximum_iterations", None)  # Ignore.
    return orig_while_loop(*args, **kwargs)


control_flow_ops.while_loop = patched_while_loop
```

Note that this is not bulletproof, i.e. it will fail if `maximum_iterations` is given as a positional (as opposed to keyword) argument, but it should "fix" `LSTM` in your case.

Comment: Thank you Sergei for your information. When I run your code, there is a SyntaxError pointing to orig. Do you know why?

Comment: Sorry, the previous version was Python3-only. I've updated the snippet to work on both 2 and 3.